# retrieve avatar user with auth and polymorphic relation

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-4, polymorphic-associations, avatar

i try to retrieve the avatar of my user when he log on my app.

Actually for the best practice i use polymorphic relation with a images table.

My images table looks like .

```
Schema::create('images', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('path');
        $table->string('alt');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('link');
        $table->integer('imageable_id');
        $table->string('imageable_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

My path is related to my avatar and in imageable_id user_id relation and imageable_type the model associated (User).

But when i check if the user is log and after try to access at my object with

```
@if(Auth::user()->image )
<img alt="" src="{{????????}}">
@endif
```

In my model User i have my relation like that

```
 public function image(){
    return $this->morphMany('Image','imageable');
}
```

How to access to my path of my image of user with Auth::user()->image

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since morphMany() allows multiple relationships, I would first rename the method to images():

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Image','imageable');
}
```

Then, I would create another method on User model, for instance defaultImage(), which would mean the first image:

```
public function defaultImage()
{ 
    return $this->images()->first();
}
```

Then, in your templates it would become:

```
@if(!is_empty(Auth::user()->defaultImage()))
    <img alt="" src="{{ Auth::user()->defaultImage()->path }}">
@endif
```